# Relation for Hurwitz zeta function

Tags: special-functions, zeta-functions

I would like to find a proof of the following relation for the Hurwitz zeta function
$\zeta(s,a)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{(n+a)^s}$:
$$5\zeta(2,1/3)-\zeta(2,1/6)=\frac{4\pi^2}{3}$$

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: I have not tried much other than doing a web search, because I don't know enough about the Hurwitz zeta function. I am reading a preprint where the relation is proved as a consequence of other relations that are quoted without references.

Answer (score 1):

Let $\chi_3(3n)=0,\chi_3(3n+1)=1,\chi_3(3n+2)=-1$ and its Dirichlet L-function $L(s,\chi_3)=\sum_{n\ge 1} \chi_3(n)n^{-s}$.

$$\sum_{n=1\bmod 3} n^{-2}= \frac12(L(2,\chi_3)+(1-3^{-2})\zeta(2))$$
$$\sum_{n=1\bmod 6} n^{-2}=\frac12((1-\chi_3(2) 2^{-2}) L(2,\chi_3)+(1-2^{-2})(1-3^{-2})\zeta(2))$$
Note that $L(2,\chi_3)$ doesn't have a closed-form (similarly to $\zeta(3)$), the main point is that the terms cancel, obtaining $$5\zeta(2,1/3)-\zeta(2,1/6) = 
5\cdot 3^2\sum_{n=1\bmod 3} n^{-2}-6^2 \sum_{n=1\bmod 6} n^{-2}$$
$$ = \frac{5 \cdot 3^2(1-3^{-2})-6^2(1-2^{-2})(1-3^{-2})}2 \zeta(2)=\frac43 \pi^2$$

Comment: Could you clarify what $L(2,\chi_3)$ is?

Comment: I edited ${}{}$

Comment: This is quite interesting. It seems that similar arguments should give more relations of the same type. The preprint I am reading points out that in view of the relation in my post, we can conclude that one of $\zeta(2,1/3),\zeta(2,1/6)$ is irrational. Would you know where I could find references that discuss these relations among Hurwitz zeta values? I did some web search but did not find much.